# How to compare data in two CSV files

Tags: ruby, csv, compare

I have two CSV files which have the same structure and ideally should have the same data.

I want to compare the data in them using Ruby and wanted to know if we already have a Ruby function for the same.

Comment: You could start by using the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) for working with the CSV files, at least (although there are [other CSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) [tools](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) out there for Ruby, as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Summea commented, look at the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class.

Then use:

```
#Will store each line of each file as an array of fields (so an array of arrays).
file1_lines = CSV.read("file1.csv")
file2_lines = CSV.read("file2.csv")

for i in 0..file1_lines.size
  if (file1_lines[i] == file2_lines[i]
    puts "Same #{file1_lines[i]}"
  else
    puts "#{file1_lines[i]} != #{file2_lines[i]}"
  end
end
```

Note that using `for` in Ruby is quite rare. You normally iterate using an `each` on the collections, but there are two of them here.

Also, pay attention that one of the list may be longer than the other, but this should get you started.

Comment: You could use `file1_lines.each_with_index {|line, index| ... }` and use that to read the correct line out of file2.

Comment: Agreed. I like the symmetry here between the two files. Personal preference, probably (would never use a for with a sole list).

Comment: Will not work if file2 is identical to file1 except for additional lines. One would have to use the maximum line count of both files.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone and esp. Martin !
I used max of the two files sizes and I am using that as the higher limit for the For loop

Comment: ...or, more simply, you could use

`file1_lines = CSV.read("file1.csv")`
`file2_lines = CSV.read("file2.csv")`

`file1_lines - file2_lines`

...and you will see the difference - faster and cleaner than going line-by-line.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check whether files are identical you can simply use `identical?` which is an alias for [`compare_file`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-compare_file):

```
FileUtils.identical?('file1.csv', 'file2.csv')
```

If you want to see the differences you might want to use [`diffy`](https://github.com/samg/diffy):

```
gem install diffy
puts Diffy::Diff.new('file1.csv', 'file2.csv',  :source => 'files')
```

It produces diff-like output which can be nicely formatted as HTML:

```
puts Diffy::Diff.new('file1.csv', 'file2.csv',  :source => 'files').to_s(:html_simple)
```